# Is it possible to identify what's the nearest street on google maps?

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Is there a way to know the nearest street without using the Directions API of google? Like Uber and 99 does.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogZMM.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Roads API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/intro) exactly [Nearest Roads](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/roads/nearest) request like:

`https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=60.170880,24.942795|60.170879,24.942796|60.170877,24.942796&key=<YOUR_API_KEY>`

to get JSON response like:

```
{
  "snappedPoints": [
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170877918672588,
        "longitude": 24.942699821922421
      },
      "originalIndex": 0,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170876898776406,
        "longitude": 24.942699912064771
      },
      "originalIndex": 1,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    },
    {
      "location": {
        "latitude": 60.170874902634374,
        "longitude": 24.942700088491474
      },
      "originalIndex": 2,
      "placeId": "ChIJNX9BrM0LkkYRIM-cQg265e8"
    }
  ]
}
```

Than, you can pass the `placeId` to the [Places API](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/places/) or the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to get the names of nearest road segments from JSON response.